# Why is 30 the default length for VARCHAR when using CAST?

Tags: sql, sql-server, casting

In SQL server 2005 this query

```
select len(cast('the quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog' as varchar))
```

returns 30 as length while the supplied string has more characters. This seems to be the default. Why 30, and not 32 or any other power of 2?

**[EDIT]** I am aware that I should always specifiy the length when casting to varchar but this was a quick let's-check-something query. Questions remains, why 30?

Comment: Holy crap--I didn't know CAST would truncate like this. I always assumed that the returning varchar would be sized to fit what CAST was stuffing into it. I have some code to check up on...bbl

Comment: Would you rather it be 255, like Informix, Sybase and other DB's default? (see my answer below)

Comment: A younger version of me made this mistake many years ago running against many thousands of rows where most of the values were less than 30 chars, but several thousand were over 30 chars, so visual validation failed, and I learned a great lesson that day that I will never forget. Also learned to always use transactions! :/

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Why don't you specify the varchar length? ie:

```
SELECT CAST('the quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog' AS VARCHAR(45))
```

As far as why 30, that's the default length in SQL Server for that type.

From [char and varchar (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176089.aspx):

> When n is not specified in a data definition or variable declaration statement, the default length is 1. *When n is not specified when using the CAST and CONVERT functions, the default length is 30.*

Comment: +1.  Why wouldn't you set the length?  Not setting it is asking for trouble.

Comment: It was a quick and dirty query, so that why I didn't specify. Thanks for pointing me to the docs though where it is mentioned though.

Comment: You are lucky you used it there, if you had specified a parameter as varchar with no length then you would have gotten a 1 character varchar. Always alwys specify a length when casting to varchar or creating a varaiable that is varchar or nvarchar.

Answer (score 33):

On your question as to why 30 and not 32 or any other power of 2, the storage size is n + 2 bytes for varchar(n), which makes the byte storage size 32 for a string of length 30. Might be that this is what they looked at?

Then just a point of clarity on some of the comments: The default length for an unspecified length varchar field is n=1. The default string length that CAST or CONVERT returns for a conversion of this data type is 30.

Very cool question!

Comment: `varchar(30)` was the datatype of `sysname` back then (and still is the max length of identifiers in Oracle). Maybe they just thought it would be a convenient default compared with say 14 or 62.

Comment: @MartinSmith Could be Martin, and an interresting fact, but once again, it's not the default length for the data type, but rather only for what CAST and CONVERT returns for this data type. If they wanted to go with sysname I assume they would have made the default size for the data type itself 30 , and not 1. But we are all quessing here ;->

Comment: Hoping for a response from a credible and/or official source :)

Answer (score 5):

Microsoft chose 30 as the default length for CHAR and VARCHAR in SQL Server, Access' Jet DB engine and several other of their products. It originates from the old days when a name or address column's default length was initially set to 30. Other DB's like Informix default to 20 for CHAR and 255 for VARCHAR.

Comment: This is the behaviour in Sybase too so I presume predates Microsoft's involvement.

Comment: Any pointer to a document explaining this behaviour (default length of name and address columns?)

Comment: Not really!.. But if you look at the length, 30, its been widely used for those types of columns throughout the industry. [MSDN link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa258242%28v=sql.80%29.aspx)  _"Remarks

When n is not specified in a data definition or variable declaration statement, the default length is 1. When n is not specified with the CAST function, the default length is 30."_

Comment: My theory is that default 30 character length originated from the U.S. Postal Service specs for name and address lines. [see here](http://pe.usps.gov/cpim/ftp/pubs/pub28/pub28.pdf)

Comment: @FrankR. - this should really be an answer.

Answer (score 4):

My theory is that default 30 character length originated from the U.S. Postal Service specs for name and address lines:

http://pe.usps.gov/cpim/ftp/pubs/pub28/pub28.pdf

Answer (score 3):

I don't know why they chose 30, but it was the same in Sybase SQL Server, which Microsoft's SQL Server was developed from. It seems to be a peculiarity of those RDBMSs as it's not in the SQL standards, and other servers differ in their behaviour.

Comment: According to the SQL standard, a cast to VARCHAR with no length should be a cast to VARCHAR(1).  That's not useful - so you should always provide a length.  There's a case that 30 is a better default than 1; I'd even agree.  But why 30 instead of 25, 32, 40, 64, ... aaah; that way lies madness!

Answer (score 0):

Default size with convert/cast has nothing to do with the memory allocation and hence the default value (ie 30) is not related to any power of 2.

regarding why 30, this is microsoft's guideline which gives this default value so as to cover the basic data in first 30 characters.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176089.aspx

Although one can always alter the length during conversion/cast process

```
select len(cast('the quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog' as varchar(max)))
```

Comment: This link was already posted by @curtisk. Also where in this doc does it state they choose the default ' to cover the basic data in first 30 characters.' ?

Comment: When n is not specified when using the CAST and CONVERT functions, the default length is 30. Reference : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176089.aspx

Comment: Err? I already accepted the answer that linked to same documentation as you did. You have provided no new insight whatsoever

Comment: I just answered to the question which you asked for the documentation in your 1st comment. Unfortunately I didn't checked the answer you accepted