# SQL Server Concatenate string column value to 5 char long

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

Scenario:

I have a table1(col1 char(5)); A value in table1 may '001' or '01' or '1'.

Requirement:

Whatever value in col1, I need to retrive it in 5 char length concatenate with leading '0' to make it 5 char long.

Technique I applied:

```
select right(('00000' + col1),5) from table1;
```

I didn't see any reason, why it doesn't work? but it didn't.
Can anyone help me, how I can achieve the desired result?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Since you're using a fixed width column, it's already of size 5 (with whitespace). You need to trim it:

```
DECLARE @table1 TABLE (col1 char(5))

INSERT INTO @table1 (col1) VALUES ('12345')
INSERT INTO @table1 (col1) VALUES ('1')

SELECT RIGHT('00000'+RTRIM(col1),5) FROM @table1

-- Output:
-- 12345
-- 00001
```

Or use `varchar` instead:

```
DECLARE @table2 TABLE (col1 varchar(5))

INSERT INTO @table2 (col1) VALUES ('12345')
INSERT INTO @table2 (col1) VALUES ('1')

SELECT RIGHT('00000'+col1,5) FROM @table2

-- Output:
-- 12345
-- 00001
```

Comment: No problem. Here's another SQL Server gotcha you may run into, this time with `varchar` columns: if you don't spec a length, they default to 30. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/359257/why-is-the-default-length-for-varchar-30-when-using-cast

Comment: +1 for not using REPLICATE ;-) example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3151503/tsql-scalar-function-need-to-return-a-concatenated-value/3151781#3151781

Answer (score 1):

If you are storing the data in a CHAR field you are probably getting right spaces buffered with blanks.  e.g. 01 = "01    ".  If your do a RIGHT("00000" + value, 5) it'll still be the original value.  You need to do a RTRIM() on the value or store the data in a VARCHAR field.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the char(5) field is always 5 characters long, not matter what you put into it. If you insert '01' into the field, the value stored is actually '01   ' (note the trailing spaces).

Try this:

```
select right(('00000' + replace(col1, ' ', '')), 5)
```

Edit: I will leave my answer here as an example, but Michael's answer using rtrim is better.

Answer (score 0):

you need to store your data in a consistent manner, so you don't need to write queries to format the data each time.  this will fix your existing data:

```
UPDATE table1
    SET col1= RIGHT('00000'+ISNULL(RTRIM(col1),''),5)
```

now every time you select you only have to do this:

```
SELECT col1 FROM table1
```

however, you must make sure that the data is formatted properly (leading zeros) every time it is inserted.  I'd add a check constraint just to make sure:

```
ALTER TABLE table1 ADD CONSTRAINT
    CK_table1_col1 CHECK (LEN(col1)=5)
```

and when you insert do this:

```
INSERT INTO table1
        (col1, ...
    VALUES
        (RIGHT('00000'+ISNULL(RTRIM(@col1),''),5)
```