# returning a concatenated value from a TSQL scalar function

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, user-defined-functions

I am writing a scalar function in T-SQL. The function should insert leading zeros into an input field of numbers the length of the input can vary in length, i,e,. 123, 1234567, 9876543210 and so forth.

I am not certain that I have defined the fields correctly as I am trying include both an Input variable and an output variable which is new to me. I am trying in insert leading zeros in front of input field and return the value input with leading zeros.

```
ALTER FUNCTION dbo.FN_ZeroPad
(
 @FN_Input_No   varchar(13)
)
RETURNS  varchar(13)
AS
BEGIN

declare @FN_PadZero  varchar (13),
  @Return   varchar (13)
Set  @FN_PadZero = '0000000000000'

select @Return =
      Case
   When @FN_Input_No is null then 'Missing'
    When @FN_Input_No < = 0 then '0000000000000'
   When @FN_Input_No > 0 then  (@FN_PadZero + @FN_Input_No)
  else null End

 RETURN @return
End
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this to pad your input with zero for the string when it's less than 13 chars.

```
ALTER FUNCTION dbo.FN_ZeroPad
(
 -- the parameters for the function here
 @FN_Input_No   varchar(13)
)
RETURNS  varchar(13)
AS
BEGIN

declare @Return   varchar(13)

  SELECT @return = RIGHT(REPLICATE('0', 13) + @FN_Input_No, 13 ) 

 RETURN @return
End
```

Comment: That Works! That is so much easier than I was going about it. Thanks so very much for your response!

Comment: As stated by gbn, no need to use the REPLICATE() function.

Comment: @user78739 thanks for your input on a question that's 2.5 years old.

Answer (score 2):

Just one line needed: no need to bother with LEN or REPLICATE or ISNULL or CONVERT or CAST or local variables...

```
ALTER FUNCTION dbo.FN_ZeroPad
(
 -- the parameters for the function here
 @FN_Input_No   varchar(13)
)
RETURNS  varchar(13)
AS
BEGIN
    RETURN RIGHT('0000000000000' + @FN_Input_No, 13)
END
```

Answer (score 1):

Your function won't work as written.  You're building a string bigger than the size of the variable and when you assign to the `@return` variable, its going to take the left most characters, so it will always return `0000000000000`.

Your best bet is to use this function to do your padding which gives you much more flexibility than what you're trying to use as you can specify how many characters to pad with (up to the length of your return variable) as well as change the padding character):

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[PadString] 
(    @Seq varchar(16),
    @PadWith char(1),
    @PadLength int
) 
RETURNS varchar(16) AS

BEGIN 
    declare @curSeq varchar(16)
    SELECT @curSeq = ISNULL(REPLICATE(@PadWith, @PadLength - len(ISNULL(@Seq ,0))), '') + @Seq
    RETURN @curSeq
END
```

Use of this would be

```
SELECT dbo.PadString ('13', '0', 5)
```

User Defined Functions can be used in select statements as another column if needed.  They provide greater flexibility in their use than stored procedures at the expense of requiring a single return value, which is what you have in this case, so a UDF fits perfectly.

This function copied from here:

http://blogs.ugidotnet.org/fgiossi/archive/2007/11/15/how-to-format-a-value-using-t-sql.aspx

Comment: cool, I have an answer that met the need, but I very much appreciate this input too. I think this will be very useful too.

Comment: Check out UDFs, though.  If you're new to T-SQL, they are extremely useful as you can use them as a column in a select statement which opens up many new avenues of use.

Answer (score 0):

```
RIGHT('0000000000000'+[field], 13) AS aliasName
```

Comment: You might want to add just a little bit of text to your answer to explain how this solves the problem and perhaps also why you think this is a better answer than any previously given answers, including the one accepted by OP.