# difference between varchar and varchar(50) in CAST expression?

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance

What is the difference between varchar and varchar(50) in SQL Server ?

```
SELECT CAST(customer_id AS varchar) AS Expr1 FROM tbl_customer
```

VS

```
SELECT CAST(customer_id AS varchar(50)) AS Expr1 FROM tbl_customer
```

Comment: [Truncation can occur differently](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/8998e/3) (but I don't know what the default limit is)

Comment: [Why is 30 the default length for VARCHAR when using CAST?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/359257/why-is-30-the-default-length-for-varchar-when-using-cast)

Comment: One is a bug waiting to happen.

Comment: [Just always specify the expected and desired length](https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length.aspx). What could you possibly gain by being lazy? Those two microseconds you saved will not change your life or even your minute.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Varchar by default is created with a length of 30 if no length is provided.

See:

```
declare @test varchar(100)
select @test = '1234567890123456789012345678901234567890'

SELECT CAST(@test AS varchar) as resultDefaultLength, 
    CAST(@test AS varchar(50)) as           resultSpecifiedLength
```

Output:

```
resultDefaultLength resultSpecifiedLength
123456789012345678901234567890  1234567890123456789012345678901234567890
```

As long as your customer_ids aren't longer than 30 characters, there will be no difference.

EDIT:

as jpw pointed out:

> This is true in the context of CAST/CONVERT, but otherwise the default
>   length is 1 char. Docs: When n is not specified in a data definition
>   or variable declaration statement, the default length is 1. When n is
>   not specified when using the CAST and CONVERT functions, the default
>   length is 30.

e.g. When declaring a varchar (and potentially other things?), if no length is given, it will have a length of 1.  Taking the example from above and modifying slightly:

```
declare @test varchar
select @test = '1234567890123456789012345678901234567890'

SELECT CAST(@test AS varchar) as resultDefaultLength, 
    CAST(@test AS varchar(50)) as           resultSpecifiedLength
```

Output:

```
resultDefaultLength resultSpecifiedLength
1   1
```

Comment: This is true in the context of CAST/CONVERT, but otherwise the default length is 1 char. Docs: _When n is not specified in a data definition or variable declaration statement, the default length is 1. When n is not specified when using the CAST and CONVERT functions, the default length is 30._

Comment: @jpw this is good to know, do you have a specific example of this occuring?  Like... if you were to create a table column of varchar, would its length be 1 or 30?

Comment: It would be 1, you can test it with your own example, just remove the (100) :)

Comment: ah! indeed extra words for allowing me to push enter :O

Comment: You might want to update your answer to reflect the difference in default length when using CAST/CONVERT.

Answer (score 1):

As per [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176089.aspx) if no length is specified for varchar it will default to 30 when using CAST. If you have not specified length then SQL Server quietly truncates the value and can lead to unexpected bug.