# SQL Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'AJH 123' to data type int

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a select statement what i need to run a case statement on it to check for a value first and then enter decide which column to get.

the start of the call is this

```
select 
case when req.ReportStatusCode in ('draft','submitted') then 
req.ID else 
req.reportNumber
end as [Request Id \ Report Number],
```

however when I call this i get an error

> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'AJH 123' to data type int.

this is the report number field and ive no idea how i could stop this.

any and all help much appreciated

Comment: what's the data type of ID and reportNumber?

Comment: Look at [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190309.aspx) post in MSDN. It explains why you get this error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
case when req.ReportStatusCode in ('draft','submitted')
then cast(req.ID as varchar(255)) else  cast(req.reportNumber as varchar(255)) end
```

Make sure `case` returns the same data type.

Comment: thank you that has worked, but i have to wait 12 mintues before i can accept the answer

Comment: don't be lazy specify a length or the varchar, it is a bad habit to use.  It will default to length 1 in some situations, have fun debugging that! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/359257/why-is-30-the-default-length-for-varchar-when-using-cast

Answer (score 1):

This is because case statement should evaluate to one type so it converts varchar to int here. Explicitly convert int to varchar:

```
select 
case when req.ReportStatusCode in ('draft','submitted') then 
     cast(req.ID as varchar(100)) else 
     req.reportNumber
end as [Request Id \ Report Number],
```