# Simple SQL Variable Assignment Only Returns One Letter: Why?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

All I'm trying to do with code is copy the dot-notated schema and table name into a variable, and, for some reason, all it gives me is the first letter:

```
DECLARE @LABEL NVARCHAR

SELECT
    @LABEL = LABEL
FROM(
     SELECT
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY T.NAME) AS ROW_NUM,
        CONCAT(S.name, '.', T.name) AS LABEL
    FROM sys.tables AS T
        INNER JOIN sys.schemas AS S
            ON T.schema_id = S.schema_id
    WHERE [object_id] <> '917578307' --the diagram table
) AS D
WHERE
    ROW_NUM = 1

SELECT
    @LABEL
```

Currently, the tables I'm using are in the dbo schema, so all I get back is "d". What am I doing wrong?

Comment: More info here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359257/why-is-30-the-default-length-for-varchar-when-using-cast

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This statement:

```
DECLARE @LABEL NVARCHAR;
```

Does not have a length.  Without a length -- in this context -- SQL Server defines the variable with only one character.

You need a length:

```
DECLARE @LABEL NVARCHAR(255);
```

When using character declarations in SQL Server, *always* include the length.

Comment: -__-...wow. Thanks...I can't believe it was something that simple.